# What are the byte sizes of basic data types in C

Tags: c

I have a pretty basic question to which I am not able to find concrete answers

By default what are the sizes of an int, short, long in C? when I say int a, is it signed by default ?

Also what is the size of unsigned values of the same. i.e unsigned int, unsigned short etc ?

I am using mac os x and xcode to compile/run. I tried doing sizeof (int) and it returns 4 bytes for both "int" and "unsigned int". What is the size difference between signed and unsigned ?

Comment: Responding to the last part of your question, the differences between signed and unsigned integer types of the same fundamental (`int`, `long`, etc) is covered in C99 §6.2.6.2. Its rather lengthy, but a fairly straight-up read if you're interested in hunting it down. (and pay particular attention to paragraph #2.)

Comment: Technically, the size of the data types is implementation-defined. But generally int is 4 chars (sizeof gives you the # of chars, which is the basic unit -- CHAR_BIT gives the number of bits per char, which is almost always 8 (which makes a char equivalent to a byte)). Unsigned data types have the same size (though not range) as their sized counterparts, which are usually signed by default (the exception is char, which can be unsigned by default). short is usually 2 chars wide. Long can be 64-bit (8 chars), but on Windows is generally the same as int (hence the amusingly-named `long long`).

Answer (score 1):

It's always platform and implementation dependent. Sometimes some types are the same size on one implementation and not on another. 
Welcome to step one in developing carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Signed and unsigned values have the same size. In the signed form the most significant bit is the sign, while in the unsigned form the extra bit allow the type to hold greater values. For example a signed type of 32 bits can hold a value in -(2^31) to 2^31 - 1 and an unsigned type of 32 bits can hold a value of 0 to 2^32 - 1.

The size of each type is system dependent. If you need a variable to be of an expecific size, you can use the types from [stdint.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html), so int32_t will always have 32 bits, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Signed and unsigned ints are the same size. The upper bit is the sign bit.

int is signed by default.

shorts are typically 2 bytes, int's are typically 4. longs are usually 4 or 8.
All of these are platform dependent and you should use sizeof() to discover them.

Answer (score 0):

Most systems today, including those Intel ones, use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for representing signed integers.
Therefore usually you get `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(signed int)`.

The number of bits for a certain type is only loosely defined by the specification and therefore mostly compiler/platform dependent. Sometimes an int might be 16bit, other times 32bits. Read the documentation of your compiler for more information (e.g. [gcc](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Integer-Types)), and keep that in mind when writing portable code.